# Как написать цикл в Makefile?

Tags: makefile

Есть файлы `lab1.с`, `lab2.с`, …, `labN.c`. Нужно написать правило в Makefile, которое бы компилировало каждый файл, т. е. что-то типа:

```
for (i = 1; i < N; i++):
   labi.o : labi.c
     g++ -c labi.c
```

Подскажите, как написать это в Makefile.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если вам нужно из каждого файла исходного кода скомпилировать соответствующий объектный файл:

```
lab1.c -> lab1.o
lab2.c -> lab2.o
      ....
labN.c -> labN.o
```

то можно воспользоваться **[pattern rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Pattern-Examples.html#Pattern-Examples)**:

```
%.o : %.c
    $(CC) -c $(CFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $< -o $@
```

Можно сделать еще короче, использовав **[implicit rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Using-Implicit.html#Using-Implicit)**:

```
%.o : %.c
```

Answer (score 1):

Используйте обобщённый знак `*`:

```
labi.o: lab*.c
   g++ -c $?
```